# SQLite - Change column that Foreign Refrences

Tags: django, database, sqlite

So I currently have two tables (Made using the Django Models), In Short.. One that provides the parameters for a lookup, and the other that provides a history for the lookup. The second table currently references the primary key of the first table in order for it to be linked. This is all well and good until i try to input a new history lookup into the second table (as Im unsure as to what the primary key of the first is).

My question then, is there a way to relate the second tables foreign key to another column in the first table (e.g. "name").

First Table

```
id(pk) - name - data1 - data2 - data3
1        bill    3       6        9
2        sam     6       3        5
3        ken     1       2        3
```

Second Table (current):

```
id(pk) - id_id(fk) - result1 - result2 - result3
1         2           12        12        14
2         2           67        32        34
3         1           34        34        23
```

Second Table (proposed):

```
id(pk) - name_id(fk) - result1 - result2 -result3
1        sam            12        12       14
2        sam            67        32       34
3        bill           34        34       23
```

So pretty much the primary key of the first table gets replaced with the name of the first table.

All the names are unique.
Thanks for any guidance.

Comment: You can't relate a fk to a non-PK column, but you can designate the name column in the first table to be the PK since names are unique. Just add primary_key=True to the field definition of name.

Comment: Hmmm.. I was thinking about doing it that way, but the problem that i was facing is that there will be around 50k - 100k records in the table, and having a non-integer primary key really hurts database performance. 
I Guess I will have to make a compromise

Comment: but then again... If im not using the primary key interger for anything then it won't matter as i'm still using the second column for actually looking up. I might give it a go and see how it turns out....

Answer (score 0):

You can just look up the id given the name. If you need the id for 'bill', just

```
select id
from first_table
where name = 'bill';
```